# PHP - sleep() in milliseconds

Tags: php, synchronization, sleep

Does PHP provide a function to sleep in milliseconds? 
Right now, I'm doing something similar to this, as a workaround.

```
$ms = 10000;
$seconds = round($ms / 1000, 2);
sleep($seconds);
```

I'd like to know whether there is a more generic function that is available in PHP to do this, or a better way of handling this.

Comment: Why the rounding? No, there is no overload that takes milliseconds. It's straightforward enough to just do a divide by 1000.

Comment: `time_nanosleep()` and `time_sleep_until()` are other sleep functions, but I don't see them as being viable alternatives.

Comment: you can execute an external program with system or exec. These will allow you to use the linux (not sure about windows equivalent) sleep (if loaded) which allows for decimals.

I have used this many times to slow down requests to an API where you want more than 1 per second.
system('sleep .1');

Answer (score 97, accepted):

This is your only pratical alternative: [usleep - Delay execution in microseconds](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php)

So to sleep for two miliseconds:

```
usleep( 2 * 1000 );
```

To sleep for a quater of a second:

```
usleep( 250000 );
```

---

Note that `sleep()` works with integers, `sleep(0.25)` would execute as `sleep(0)` Meaning this function would finish immediatly.

```
$i = 0;
while( $i < 5000 )
{
  sleep(0.25);
  echo '.';
  $i++;
}
echo 'done';
```

Comment: I guess there is no function that accepts milliseconds as the parameter?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the documentation for specifically milliseconds, usleep is your only option for non-whole second granualrity.

Comment: In order to delay program execution for a fraction of a second, use usleep() as the sleep() function expects an int. For example, sleep(0.25) will pause program execution for 0 seconds.

Comment: usleep( 1000 * 1000 ); means 1 seconds that equals = sleep(1)

Comment: So if I need exactly a pause of 1.5 seconds, i have to write `sleep(1); usleep(500000);` together? That's so crappy

Comment: @Moongazer I'd write `usleep(1500000)`, or try to figure out a better way where no sleep is required.

Comment: @Scuzzy Yes I wanted to, until I saw this in the PHP docs: "Note: Values larger than 1000000 (i.e. sleeping for more than a second) may not be supported by the operating system. Use sleep() instead."

Comment: Ahhh, good times PHP